# How to save GitLab repository in Visual Studio Code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, gitlab, repository

How to connect the GitLab repository to VSCode so that you don't have to clone the repository in VSCode every time? Every time when i open VSCode i need to enter link to GitLab repository.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you deleted it, the repository is saved on your hard drive in the folder you cloned it into. When you open VSCode, you can go to the existing repo folder multiple ways:

1. File -> Open Recent -> and then you should see the recent folders you accessed. If you don't see it there,
2. File -> Open Folder -> then navigate to the proper folder.

Comment: okay i understand but there are no new files in this folder in case someone else in the group adds a new one to GitLab. So I'm wondering if there is any solution to get to the new folders in GitLab as quickly as possible.

Comment: @user18610596 Once you are in the repo folder, you simply need to `git fetch` to get the latest code copied from the remote repo to your local repo, and if you have a branch checked out that has been updated on the remote repo, you just need to `git pull` to update your local folders. Note "pulling" will be faster than re cloning every time.